# tools/means to money transfer from India to USA legally

Tags: united-states, india, money-transfer, international-transfer

I see questions [Legality](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/89432/) and [transfer for EB5](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/95713/), but does not answer on how to do the money transfer from India to USA. For USA to India transfer there are many websites/and Bank.

I left India about 25+ years ago and has been always sending money. Now I may get some money from parental properties( after sibling distribution and if left any thing for me), but what I remember India was a one way street for money transfer, one can send money there but cannot bring money from India as government controls it. So I am looking for tools that can help me bring it legally and does not take too much time( like visiting government offices/bank multiple times). As Time is money.